# How can I wait for a button to be enabled with casperjs?

Tags: javascript, wait, casperjs

I'm trying to automate a form that has the following button for submission:

```
<input type="button" class="inactiveswbuttonNew" id="btnSearch" aria-label="Search" style="border: 0px none !important; background-image: url(https://www.anthem.com/images/ProviderFinder/SearchWizard/search2_button.png);" disabled>
```

The issue is that the button is disabled until you've filled out all of the required info on the form. So, I'd like to have casperjs wait for the button to become enabled before clicking. I've tried `this.waitForSelectorTextChange('#btnSearch');` but that just times out.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had configured casperjs to include jquery when the site already had jquery loaded. This made `casper.click('selector');` fail. Remove the extra jquery and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact answer, but you can try this:

```
casper.waitForSelector(x("//input[@disabled='false']"),
function success() {
    //code
  },
function fail() {
    //code
});
```

Do not forget to set wait timeout:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.waitTimeout = 100000;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provided more code, I would be likely to play around with it.

If I had a link to the website, I might be able to provide more help.

Since I don't know which webpage it is and depending on your goals, you may be able to ignore a "disabled" button.

See if you just execute the java script that would normally be responsible for submitting the form directly after filling out the forms.

OR something like this may work as well.

```
this.click('#ctl00_myhiddenaspx_button_btn_sumbit')
```